# Is there a way to make a trait that contain an vector of itself?

Tags: rust

I'm quite new to rust and I have the following problems: I want to have trait that I call `Artifact` and the definition of an `Artifact` is that it can contains multiples `Artifact`.

My first idea was to make an `Artifact` trait that contains a vector of the `Artifact` trait:

```rust
trait Artifact
{
    type artifacts = Vec<Box<dyn Artifact>>;
}
```

I got the following error:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `artifacts` (from the trait `Artifact::Artifact`) must be specified
 --> src/Artifact.rs:4:30
  |
4 |     type artifacts = Vec<Box<dyn Artifact>>;
  |     -------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^---
  |     |                        |
  |     |                        associated type `artifacts` must be specified
  |     `artifacts` defined here
```

Is there a way in rust to make this kind of design?

Comment: Traits are like interfaces in other languages. They specify some contract and not the impl details. Basically a trait does not and must not care how you implement it.

Comment: The type in the trait or in a struct won't help you much, I think. You probably want an access function `fn artifacts(&self) -> Vec<Self>;` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define type definition in the trait as `dyn trait`, then it is an associated type and you need to specify that type on the implementation of that trait.

> Is there a way in rust to make this kind of design?

In the current stable release channel **default associated types** are not supported. But you can achieve what you need with **nightly** release channel like following:

```
#![feature(associated_type_defaults)]
trait Artifact {
    type artifacts = Vec<Box<dyn Artifact<artifacts = Self>>>;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018)

---

In **stable** release channel you can implement the closest idea like following:

```
trait Artifact {
    fn artifact_call(&self);
}

struct Artifact1 {
    inners: Vec<Box<dyn Artifact>>,
}

struct Artifact2;
struct Artifact3;

impl Artifact for Artifact1 {
    fn artifact_call(&self) {
        self.inners
            .iter()
            .for_each(|artifact| artifact.artifact_call());
    }
}

impl Artifact for Artifact2 {
    fn artifact_call(&self) {
        println!("Artifact 2 Call");
    }
}

impl Artifact for Artifact3 {
    fn artifact_call(&self) {
        println!("Artifact 3 Call");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let container_artifact = Artifact1 {
        inners: vec![Box::new(Artifact2), Box::new(Artifact3)],
    };
    container_artifact.artifact_call();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef4f67079516e2f3ffc51f5596ba00ae)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! This is exactly what I wanted to know :)